# Como se codifica/decodifica una imagen por medio de sonata media?

Tags: symfony2, doctrine

Buen día,

Estoy usando symfony2 con sonata, tengo un formulario del cual obtengo una imagen por medio de un campo "imagen" de tipo 'sonata_media_type', por lo cual en mi controlador obtengo esta imagen, mi pregunta es ¿como se codifica la imagen (la imagen que me retorna el formulario) para guardarla en la base de datos? (esto como medida de protección de la imagen).
O no se si se pueda codificar mediante una propiedad en el mismo formulario?.
De antemano agradezco su ayuda